# Filtering search by views gives results with more views than given

Tags: bug, search, views

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Search using `views:..2` criterion, e.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+views%3A..2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]%20views%3A..2)

**Observed**

1. Most of the results have more views - e.g. twenty-ish . Although some filtering does seem to happen.

**Context**

The filtering intention seems to be properly understood by the user interface, as you get "search options views<= 2" on the right-hand dide.